# Dynamically use variable in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, variables

I have some predefined variables, eg:

```
$s1 = a
$s2 = b
...
$s[x] = x
```

I have a script that connects to a device via serial port, get some data, split the string and get a value I need.
The value that I have from the string I needed to use it to get a predefined variable.

In php I do it easily like this:

```
$var1 = a
$var2 = b
...
$var[x] = x


$i = something
echo ${"var_name$i"}
```

How can I do the same in PowerShell?
I tried

```
write-host $s$i
write-host $s{$i}
write-host ${s$i}
write-host ${"s$i"}
```

with no luck...all I get is either the value of `$i` or empty space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`Get-Variable` cmdlet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849899.aspx):

```
Write-Host $(Get-Variable "s$i" -ValueOnly)
```

Comment: Thank you. Exactly what I needed. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the `Get-Variable` cmdlet:

```
Get-Variable 'i'
```